# Python Dataframe remove unwanted characters stored in a float list

Tags: python, list, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a data frame. It presents the data of a sensor coming from the field. Strangely, it stores the a list of float values in a string format. That means, quote marks at the beginning and end. There is an unwanted comma at the end. I want to get rid off them.

My code:

```
df = 
index                   col_A              col_B       
2018-12-13 09:00:03    '-1.780,-1.747,'   '-1.730,-1.647,' # Each cell of the dataframe has two float values inside it. 
2018-12-13 09:00:19    '-1.714,-1.680,'   '-1.614,-1.531,'
2018-12-13 09:37:03    '-1.797,-1.780,'   '-1.680,-1.581,'
2018-12-13 09:37:19    '-1.780,-1.730,'   '-1.680,-1.597,'
2018-12-13 10:07:17    '-1.497,-1.464,'   '-1.431,-1.398,'

for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    plt.plot(row['col_A'],row['col_B'])
plt.show()
```

Present output:

ValueError: Illegal format string '-1.780,-1.747,'; two marker symbols

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string to get the float values

```py
def parse_data(s):
    try:
        return (float(s.split(',')[0]), float(s.split(',')[1]))
    except:
        return (0.0,0.0)
        
(df['col_A_1'], df['col_A_2']) = df['col_A'].apply(parse_data)
(df['col_B_1'], df['col_B_2']) = df['col_B'].apply(parse_data)

# delete old columns no longer in use
del df['col_A']
del df['col_B']
```

| index | col_A_1 | col_A_2 | col_B_1 | col_B_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-12-13 09:00:03, | -1.780 | -1.780 | -1.730 | -1.730 |
| 2018-12-13 09:00:03, | -1.747 | -1.747 | -1.647 | -1.647 |

now you can use
'col_A_1, col_A_2 etc.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. My float list has 800 to 1000 elements. So, I end up having those many columns right.

Comment: each of you column has 2 float numbers separated by a comma. So effectively you will get 2 float numbers from each column. I am not quite sure how you are using them. But if you want to store each float number in a single column then you will end up with twice the number of your columns.